# Retriving two models and order them by date

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to retrive the 20 most recent elements from two differents models `Post` and `Link` and rank them by the field `created_at` in descending order.

Here is the link class

```
class Link extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
  public $incrementing = false;

  public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author');
  }

  public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
  }
}
```

And here the post class

```
class Post extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
  public $incrementing = false;

  public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author');
  }

  public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
  }
}
```

How can I do that with eloquent (I'm using it outside Laravel, with Slim)?

Comment: Is there and reference ket between post and link table?

Comment: Nope they are two differents things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `merge` method was the answer :

```
$posts = \App\Models\Post::where('draft', false)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(20)->get();
$links = \App\Models\Link::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(20)->get();

$result = $posts->merge($links)->sortByDesc('created_at')->take(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to get recent records

> orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

Comment: But they are two differents models, so they are in different table.. I think I will have to retrive the 20 mosts recents records from each table and after order the results... But I stil don't have any idea how to do this

Comment: You want to get results by matching any of the column in two models?

Comment: you can use join query

Comment: No I just want the 20 most recents entries from the 2 tables

Comment: Join query are for extracting entries from different table with something in commun no? Like author or category?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137870/discussion-between-vinothini-and-wizix).